# How to execute .jar file in TCL

Tags: eclipse, exec, tcl

I'm trying to execute a .exe file through a TCL program I'm writing. The line is

```
exec "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\folder\jarfile.exe"
```

The error I am getting is

```
couldn't execute "C:UsersownerDesktopfolderjarfile.exe": no such file or directory
while executing
    "exec "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\folder\jarfile.exe""
(file "C:\Users\owner\workspace\Test\connectiontest.tcl" line 53)
```

I am using Eclipse to write the program in; I have Eclipse set up with TCL environment so the program does work. It's just that I can't get the `.exe` file to execute.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I didn't realize the file is `jarfile.jar`, not `jarfile.exe`. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the slashes:

```
exec "C:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\folder\\jarfile.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the jar file into a .exe and tried your answer, and it worked!

Comment: glad for you! if it worked remember to check the answer as the correct one :)

Comment: You could also use braces `exec {C:\Users\owner\Desktop\folder\jarfile.exe}`

Comment: Or swap the direction of the slashes: `exec "C:/Users/owner/Desktop/folder/jarfile.exe"` (though this is not such a good idea for arguments unless you use `file nativename` to reverse before handing to an external program),